# Upgrade HDD on PlayStation 4, clone with dd and enlarge the partition using GParted?

Tags: filesystems, partition, hard-disk, dd, gparted

Will it work if I use the `dd` command to clone the almost full 1TB hard disk drive from my PlayStation 4 to a new 2TB drive, then resize the partition using GParted to utilize the full capacity of the new drive, and finally install the new drive into the game console?

I've come across procedures using programs like MiniTool Partition Magic and EaseUS that run on Windows OS, which I don't have, but I haven't found similar options on any of my Linux distributions (Linux Mint 21, antiX, and Mageia).

Output of `lsblk`:

```
sda 8:0 0 931.5G 0 disk 
├─sda1 8:1 0 512M 0 part 
├─sda3 8:3 0 1G 0 part 
├─sda5 8:5 0 16M 0 part 
├─sda7 8:7 0 128M 0 part 
├─sda9 8:9 0 1G 0 part 
├─sda10 8:10 0 1G 0 part 
├─sda11 8:11 0 1G 0 part 
├─sda12 8:12 0 1G 0 part 
├─sda13 8:13 0 8G 0 part 
├─sda17 259:0 0 1G 0 part 
├─sda19 259:1 0 8G 0 part 
├─sda25 259:2 0 6G 0 part 
├─sda27 259:3 0 885.9G 0 part 
├─sda29 259:4 0 1G 0 part 
└─sda31 259:5 0 16G 0 part 

sdb 8:16 1.8T
```

Comment: To clone PS4 hard drive, please check https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/clone-ps3-ps4-hard-drive.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that will work. You can use `dd` for that.

Your running target devices must have the same size or must be bigger.

You can't clone a bigger device to a smaller drive or clone only the used space of a partition with `dd`!

If the merging of the empty and full partition doesn't work on the first attempt, just try it again.

Once you have cloned/copied the disks, try it out on your gaming console, and then proceed with the merging.

Check with `lsblk` the device names and change [HD1TB] with your HD-1TB(Source) and [HD2TB] with your HD-2TB(Destination)

`dd if=/dev/[HD1TB] of=/dev/[HD2TB] bs=1M status=progress`

- `if`=INPUT/SOURCE
- `of`=OUTPUT/TARGET
- `bs`=BLOCKS SIZE FOR COPY There are different blocksize that can be used I prefer 1MB, you can speed the process up or slow done with this setting, you have to find by yourself what is the best option
- `status=progress` STATUS IN REALTIME

[How to Upgrade or Replace Your PS4 and PS4 Pro Hard Drive](https://www.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/How_to_Upgrade_or_Replace_Your_PS4_and_PS4_Pro_Hard_Drive)

I'm not sure anymore if you can do the merge directly from the playstation.

> The PlayStation 4 can typically detect and read external drives such as hard drives and USB sticks formatted with `exFAT` or `FAT32`, but `FAT32` is an older format, it is recommended to use `exFAT`

**Update after `lsblk` ouput**

*This is your command now:*

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress`

1. After you have executed the `dd` command (it will likely take a long time), you rebuild the hard drive(the new 2TB, sdb) into the PlayStation.
2. Than check if you can boot the system before attempting to partition or merge the remaining disk space.

Comment: I usually in this cases take out the PC hdd, start it with a Live usb and proceed...
For me it looks the safest way to go!
And in this case it should be that way not only for safety but because my PC only have 2 SATA cables and to put two extra disks more cables are needed....
Thanks again!

Comment: I can not connect the other disks if I do not remove the existing ones! Not enough cables in my PC. Yes there are 4 or maybe more ports in the mb but just two SATA cables...

Comment: It is going on... it will take some time, I wonder

Comment: I am reading https://www.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/How_to_Upgrade_or_Replace_Your_PS4_and_PS4_Pro_Hard_Drive

Comment: mint@mint:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M status=progress
1000173731840 bytes (1.0 TB, 931 GiB) copied, 12315 s, 81.2 MB/s
953869+1 records in
953869+1 records out
1000204886016 bytes (1.0 TB, 932 GiB) copied, 12318.6 s, 81.2 MB/s
Will test it now!
More to come tomorrow...

Comment: gparted offered to fix the unused space....
ShoulI proceed or test it before on the PS4?

Comment: Searching I found that PS4 uses PFS filesystem loosely related to UFS
https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/PFS
gparted does not fix amything!
The disk as cloned have the same size of the original one! the rest ins not partitioned

Comment: The empty space have no partition at all...  should I made a partition? which type? Format it ? exFat or Fat 32? mbr or gpt?
As it is just now it works just as the old one.

Comment: New primary partition created and format as exFat... Lets see what the PS4 says...

Comment: Again it was already tested but the unallocated space was not recognized.
I have to go to do some tasks quite far away. It will take me, maybe, the whole afternoon...

Answer (score -1):

No one can modify the Play Station's partitions or file system! It is a proprietary system derived from FreeBSD but still different. The only way it works is following Sony's instructions.
No Gparted, nor Easeus, nor Aomei, nor Minitool PM, understand Play Station partitions and file system. No one will reverse engineer that because they face a battle against a mammoth powerful enterprise...
I tried all! From UFS and ZFS to all those programs I previously mentioned!
No one worked!
Only Sony's way work!